# Displaying Barchart or Pie Chart in QGIS HTML Map Tip

Tags: qgis

I'm exploring the possibilities of enhancing HTML map tips in QGIS. I have a layer with two attributes, "Attribute 1" and "Attribute 2". I'm interested in displaying a graphical representation, such as a barchart or pie chart, for these attributes within the HTML map tip.

Is it feasible to achieve this directly within the HTML map tip in QGIS? If so, how would one integrate the necessary code for generating the charts based on the attribute values?

I've recently experimented with HTML map tips in QGIS and attempted to include additional content beyond a simple title. However, despite my efforts, only the title seems to be rendering.

```
<h1>Bar Chart HTML</h1>

<div class="chart-wrap vertical">
  <h2 class="title">Bar Chart HTML Example:  Using Only HTML And CSS</h2>
  
  <div class="grid">
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:85%;" data-name="Your Blog" title="Your Blog 85%"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:23%;" data-name="Medium" title="Medium 23%"></div>
     <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:7%;" data-name="Tumblr" title="Tumblr 7%"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:38%;" data-name="Facebook" title="Facebook 38%"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:35%;" data-name="YouTube" title="YouTube 35%"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:30%;" data-name="LinkedIn" title="LinkedIn 30%"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-value:5%;" data-name="Twitter" title="Twitter 5%"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="--bar-v[% "Poc_obyv_2001" %]alue:20%;" data-name="Other" title="Other 20%"></div>    
  </div>
</div>
```